# Windows Server 2008 firewall not allowing a port range

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2008, port-forwarding

I have a windows server 2008 SP1 Datacenter instaled on my PC. My problem is that windows firewall is **not accepting port ranges**, like 2300-3000, 5500-6000 and so on..

Here is a similar image from my rules wizard:

[image]

**Should be like this image:**

[image]

All updates were installed, and there are no updates pending, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's "Windows Server 2008", and then there's "Windows Server 2008 R2".

Windows 2008 is the same era/kernel as Vista, and 2008R2 is Windows 7.

In Vista, and I would imagine/assume in 2008 (non-R2) as well, you can't add ranges to the Firewall, but you can in Windows 7/2008R2.

I would guess that the example screenshot you're following was created on and targeted at 2008R2.

Check out this related SU question and answer for a way to add many ports to the Vista firewall in batch:

[Vista Windows Firewall - how to block all ports apart from 1 on a particular subnet?](https://superuser.com/questions/619377/vista-windows-firewall-how-to-block-all-ports-apart-from-1-on-a-particular-sub)

The answer there should apply exactly the same to your Windows Server 2008. You'll just have to adjust the rule to match your purposes.